# Insert after update query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an update query that I stored in a stored procedure.

I want to insert the updated query just after I execute the stored procedure.
here is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_assign_account]
    @id_agency int,
    @month nvarchar(2),
    @regional nvarchar(20),
    @top int,
    @assigned_by nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [AMAS].[dbo].[tbl_sample] 
    SET id_agency = @id_agency, 
        status = 'assigned', 
        stage = 'STA', 
        tgl_assign = GETDATE(), 
        assigned_by = @assigned_by  
    WHERE id_sample IN (SELECT  TOP (@top) a.id_sample 
                        FROM [AMAS].[dbo].[tbl_sample] a
                        LEFT JOIN mysystem.lapkeu.dbo.groupbranch b ON a.branch_id = b.BranchID
                        WHERE a.is_delete = '0' 
                          AND a.status = 'not assigned' 
                          AND a.stage = 'AMA' 
                          AND MONTH(a.insert_at) = @month
                          AND a.branch_id IN (SELECT branch_id 
                                              FROM mysystem.lapkeu.dbo.groupbranch 
                                              WHERE GroupBranchID IN (SELECT b.group_branch_id 
                                                                      FROM [AMAS].[dbo].[tbl_collector_agency] a
                                                                      JOIN [AMAS].[dbo].[tbl_area_collector] b ON a.id_collector = b.id_collector
                                                                      WHERE a.id_agency = @id_agency)
        ) 
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    )

    // can i put insert query here??
END
```

or can I get the updated id? Because I use random data to update, so I don't initialize the id before update.

Comment: You want the [Output Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [`Output clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as @Dale K's comment

```
DECLARE @Updated table(id_agency int, .. // Any property as you want)

UPDATE [AMAS].[dbo].[tbl_sample] SET id_agency = @id_agency, status = 'assigned', stage='STA', tgl_assign = getdate(), assigned_by = @assigned_by  
OUTPUT deleted.id_agency // Any property as you want
INTO @Updated
WHERE id_sample 
IN (////)

SELECT * FROM @Updated
```

From `@Updated` result, you can dosomething as you wish: `Insert`, `Select`, etc.

Read the following tutorial to have a better understanding.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-update-statements

**Example**

[image]

Comment: You need to put it `OUTPUT .. INTO @@Updated` right after `Set` clause.

I've just updated my answer with an example to help you have more understanding. Please take a look @Yohanes Erwin