# Update grouped rows with ID of newly inserted grouping row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to group several rows of table A and insert a new row into table B for each bunch of grouped rows.
Next to that I want to update the rows of table A with the ID of the newly inserted row.

Inserting the lines into the table with 'grouplines' is like:

```
INSERT INTO B(...,...,...)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM A
GROUP BY col1,col2
```

This will produce a list of IDs in table B. I want to update the rows of table A with the ID of the corresponding group-row of table B.

Is there a possibilty to do this?

Some sample data:

[image]

After grouping table B looks like:

[image]

And then table A should look like:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need [Output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834058/9071943) before if need

Comment: Your select query makes no sense.  Typically you would not be aggregating the columns which appear in `GROUP BY`.  Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: @Tim you are right. Edited. I'll provide some sample data.

Comment: @Phong. I tried to use the OUTPUT clause but after retrieving the ID's of the newly inserted rows it is not clear which rows of the original table to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, your query potentially inserts more than one row.

I think that one solution would to use two queries: first insert in table b from table a, the update table a with newly created id(s) from table b.

```
INSERT INTO B(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 FROM A

UPDATE A
SET A.B_ID = B.B_ID
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON  A.col1 = B.col1
    AND A.col2 = B.col2
    AND A.col3 = B.col3
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was thinking. I'll use this by now. I wonder if someone has a one-step-solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Deme on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8476642be7a60bf0c3b727e232eb2a2)

You can achieve table B by using `Row_Number` like below

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Category) as ID, Name, Category
into #B
from #A
group by Name, Category
```

Then Update the table A after joining with table B like

```
Update a
set a.ID_Of_Group_row = b.ID
from #A a
inner join #B b on a.Category = b.Category
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. The ID of table B needs to be unique. It must be possible to identify the rows of table A that correspond with the row of table B in an unqiue way. Thanks anyway for the attempt.